# How to parse XML with HTML tags in the elements using Jackson?

Tags: xml, kotlin, parsing, jackson, xml-parsing

I have a XML file and try to parse it using Jackson. My XML file looks similar to this:

```
<package>
  <name>Paul Muad'dib</name>
  <description>
    This is a description, and for some reason somebody decided to put <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask">html tags inside here</a>
 </description>
</package>
```

My code for this looks something like this (I am using Kotlin, but the Java code would look basically the same):

```
class XmlThing {
  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "name")
  var name: String = ""
 
  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "description")
  var description: String = ""
}

...

val file: File = [my xml file]

val objectMapper = XmlMapper(JacksonXmlModule().apply {
        setDefaultUseWrapper(false)
    }).registerKotlinModule().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)

val xmlThing = objectMapper.readValue(file, XmlThing::class.java)
```

This results in the following error message:

```
Resolving dependencies for 'some.xml' failed with: MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.String` from Object value (token `JsonToken.FIELD_NAME`)
```

It looks like Jackson tries to interpret the HTML tag as another XML tag (I mean `<a href="blabla">albalb</a>` is a valid XML tag) and then sees the content of `<description>` as another object.

I already tried the `@JacksonXmlText` annotation, but it just resulted in the content of `<description>` not being read at all (so it's just an empty String). I would really like to keep using Jackson for this, because the project already uses it and I don't want to add more dependencies.

Answer (score -2):

Why not Jsoup..in my opinion it is much easier to extract attribute values in Jsoup.